Access Token not refreshing with Passport Strategy for Salesforce
Main purpose of the my task is to run Salesforce API tests in the pipeline with valid access token, without any manual intervention of generating it again.
To achieve this, Im trying to refresh an access token with Passport strategy and then use the new token in the following API call. The following code runs without errors but no response is coming back from the API call, which makes me think that the API call is not run. I cannot place what could be wrong here, please share your approach for a similar issue.
const passport = require('passport');
const OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2').Strategy;
const refresh = require('passport-oauth2-refresh');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const strategy = new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
    clientID: 'xxxx',
    clientSecret: 'xxxx',
    callbackURL: 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/callback' 
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // Handle authentication, e.g., save user information to session
    done(null, { accessToken, refreshToken, profile });
});

passport.use(strategy);
refresh.use(strategy);

describe('Salesforce API Test', () => {
    it('should make an authenticated API GET call to Salesforce connected app', async () => {
        const apiUrl = 'https://xxx.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v60.0/sobjects/';

        // Get the access token from the passport user object
        const user = { accessToken: null, refreshToken: null };
        passport.authenticate('oauth2', (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error('Failed to authenticate with Salesforce');
            }
            user.refreshToken = result.refreshToken;
            user.accessToken = result.accessToken;
            console.log(user.accessToken); 

            const response = fetch(apiUrl, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ user.accessToken,
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
            });
            const responseData = response.json();
            console.log(responseData);
            console.log(response.status);
       
        })
        
    });
});

